# Terminate python code without letting it finish if while loop condition is unmet in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this so far. The issue is, if `pythoncode.py` started before `8*60*60` seconds, then it can still continue running beyond `8*60*60` seconds until it finishes and only then will it stop. I need it to terminate `pythoncode.py` at exactly (loosely, +- 1 second is not an issue) `8*60*60` seconds even if it is running.

```
#! /bin/bash
end=$((SECONDS+8*60*60))

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
    python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
done
```

I'm a beginner so explaining what to do specifically with this example would be appreciated over just a general answer.

Comment: Why do you use bash or implementing the time logic, instead of doing everything inside pythoncode.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop does not work because `python3` blocks until `pythoncode.py` terminated (by itself). To manually terminate it you have to run the check in parallel (for instance by prepending `&` and putting the loop after (!) python) and have to call something like `kill` to forcefully terminate the command.

Alternatively, use GNU `timeout` (from GNU coreutils) which is designed for stuff like this.
Here we run the python script repeatedly for exactly eight hours. The last run will most likely be terminated forcefully.

```
timeout 8h sh -c 'while true; do python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py; done'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Soccowi will this example you gave repeat the python script if it finished before 8h or will it only do it once? I need it to also rerun the script if it finishes earlier than 8h.

Comment: In the first version of this answer python ran only once. From the question I didn't get that you actually want to *repeat* the python script for 8h rather than doing a single run. I adjusted the answer. Now it will repeat the python script.

Comment: Thanks. Now your code has the same outcome as the one in my original question except with cutting the process in the middle?